# Ubuntu Server - awstats - virtual hosts - Do I need separate log files for each host?

Tags: 14.04, networking, server, apache2

Ok, so I got my virtual hosts all setup and they are working great.  The problem is my awstats data.  I have it setup for both of my sites but it looks like the same visitors are showing up in the results of both sites...

I had assumed that with having one access log file, awstats could go through the log and identify what traffic was for one domain and what was for the other.  Is this now how it works?

Do I need to setup an apache access log file for each virtual host?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this article from 2007!

Looks like I do need two log files:

http://www.westhost.com/blog/2007/11/09/awstats-and-multiple-domains/#.VT8JxlI8LCQ